# News ticker display

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to work out how to do a news-ticker type of loop with a very long string. My control takes a string variable that is displayed, so i need to change the variable to the correct sequence.

I was working though with something along the lines of below, which works well untill i reach the end of the string.

```
textVar = longstring.Substring(currentPos, maxStringLength)
```

But not sure how to go back to the beginning once I reach the end and add it to the . Has anyone seen any controls that simplify this process or reccomendations on how to do the code?

The currentPoswas a integer to say the position in the string and maxStringLength is a variable that has the qty of character i can display at once. The string will be loaded from a database and the length will vary from 5 char onwards.

Any suggestions or pointers on how to get there will be great or if anyone has found a free control to do this it would also be suitable.

Comment: I'm missing out something but can't you reset currentPos to 0 when it equals maxStringLenght?

Comment: I would like to continue cycling so that when i'm at the end of the string, instead of jumping back to the beginning, i would like it to add it to the end of the string. Kind of like an endless loop (imagine the text being in a circle and that constant loop)

Comment: So, every time you take a substr you need to push that to the end of the string. Example `MY STRING` first 4 chars will be `MY S` so you push that to the end like `TRING MY S` and so on. Does that makes any sense?

Comment: Yep, that sound right. for that i would imagine the loop to be similar to: 'MY S', 'Y ST', ' STR', 'STRI', 'TRIN', 'RING', 'ING ', 'NG M', 'G MY'....

Comment: @StephenPefanis Do you want your text to scroll horizontally and go back when the end is reached?

Comment: @conquistador - That is the hope. I am able to get it to go to the end of the string, but the loop around to the beginning again is where I have gotten stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Timer` control to your form and set it `Enabled=True` either on Properties or on your `Form` `load`. Make a handler for its `Tick` event. Now add a `Label` then add some lines if you want.

This a handler for the `Tick`

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 1 'Sets the interval of the Timer speed
        Label1.Left = Label1.Left - 3 'How much pixel will be deducted to the left of the control
        If Label1.Left < 0 - Label1.Width Then 'Loops the strings back to right
            Label1.Left = Width '^
        End If
    End Sub
```

Both `.Interval - n` and `.Left - n` controls the speed.

Comment: Thnks, i really would like it to go into a variable as i'm using another control to display the text. additionally, this goes untill all the text is gone, i really would like it to start looping immediatly at the end of the last char.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fantastic for me.

Global variable:

```
dim TickerText as string
```

Then I got the ticker text line from an SQL query and saved it into the TickerText variable via a datatable.

```
cmdstr = "SELECT TOP(1) MAX(ID) as LastID, Highlight FROM dbo.HighlightTable Group By Highlight"

Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, con)
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable

    da1.Fill(dt1)

    Dim dv1 As DataView = dt1.DefaultView


    For Each rowview As DataRowView In dv1

        TickerText = rowview(1)

    Next

    'Salesticker is my label on the main form
    SalesTicker.Text = TickerText

    'this statement starts the ticker out blank, so all text comes in from the right hand side of the screen
    SalesTicker.Left = Width
```

Then my timer code is the same as conquistador used above.  I just changed the interval to 35 to slow it way down.  It runs beautifully on a loop.

Comment: Why use a DataView? If you know you only have one row, why For-Each it?

Comment: You could user a reader just as easily, but wouldn't you still need to while loop through the reader?  I don't see much difference.

Comment: For-Each or Do-While imply more than one record.  `If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then TickerText = dt1.Rows(0)("Highlight").ToString`

Comment: Sweet.  Even better.